# Qual timezone usar para o apschedule?

Tags: python, agendamento

Estou tentando agendar uma tarefa para os dias de semana, das 8hrs até as 17hrs, de dez em dez minutos, usando o módulo apscheduler.

```py
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

cron = BackgroundScheduler(daemon=True, timezone='Etc/GMT-3')
cron.add_job(service.test, trigger='cron',
             day_of_week='mon-fri', hour='7-16', minute=10)
cron.start()
```

mas a função que eu passo para o scheduler nunca é chamada. suspeito que seja algo relacionado a timezone, mas já tentei várias e nenhuma funcionou. alguém que já passou por esse problema sabe alguma solução?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

boa noite! Aqui está uma solução que pode te ajudar:

Você pode passar a string assim:

```
cron = BlockingScheduler(timezone="america/sao_paulo")
```

E encontre a string usando thisL

```
from tzlocal import get_localzone
tz = get_localzone()
print(tz)
```